# Fetch split array "Base_experince" information from Group A and Group B outside axios and find largest base_experience from both array Using ReactJS

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, api

I have created an app to iterate pokemon with limits and this limit is split into two different arrays. For example, the limit is 8 and this limit is split into 2 different arrays with 4 elements each array 1st array is split and shown into Group A and the second array is split into Group B.

How can I show the largest value of  the `base_experience` field from both arrays group?

Refer below code to print result:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import Axios from "axios";

function App() {
  const [num1, setNum1] = React.useState([]);
  const currentArr = 0;
  let largest = 0;

  Axios.get("https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon?limit=8").then(function (
    output
  )  // Used this API to get pokemon with limits
{
    const myArray = output.data.results;
    const first = myArray.slice(0, myArray.length / 2); // Split Array Group A
    const second = myArray.slice(myArray.length / 2, myArray.length + 1); // Split Array Group B

    var firstArray = [];
    var firstArr = 0;
    var secArray = [];
    var secArr = 0;
    var num = 0;
    console.log(first.length, output.data);
    // do whatever
    

    first.map(function (i) { // Call First Function
      Axios.get(i.url).then(function (result) {
        const subDiv = document.createElement("div");

        subDiv.setAttribute("id", subDiv);
        subDiv.style.width = "100%";
        subDiv.style.border = "5px solid blue";
        subDiv.style.display = "inline-block";
        const myImg = document.createElement("img");
        myImg.setAttribute("src", result.data.sprites.front_default);
        subDiv.style.textAlign = "center";
        myImg.setAttribute("width", "100px");

        subDiv.append(myImg);

        const myName = document.createElement("h2");
        myName.innerText = "Name: " + i.name;
        subDiv.append(myName);

        const myExperience = document.createElement("h3");
        myExperience.innerText = "Experience: " + result.data.base_experience;

        subDiv.append(myExperience);
        document.getElementById("firstDiv").append(subDiv);

        firstArr = result.data.base_experience; // I want collect this result into array and find largest number from this Array
        firstArray.push(firstArr);
        alert(
          " From Group A " +
            Math.max(...firstArray) +
            " Largest Number from array " +
            firstArray
        ); // This result working fine but I want show this result outside function
      });
    });

    second.map(function (i) { // Second Array Group B call here
      Axios.get(i.url).then(function (result) {
        const secondDiv = document.createElement("secondDiv");
        secondDiv.setAttribute("id", secondDiv);
        secondDiv.style.border = "5px solid yellow";
        secondDiv.style.display = "inline";
        secondDiv.style.width = "100%";
        secondDiv.style.textAlign = "center";

        const myImg = document.createElement("img");
        myImg.setAttribute("src", result.data.sprites.front_default);
        myImg.setAttribute("width", "100px");
        secondDiv.append(myImg);

        const myName = document.createElement("h2");
        myName.innerText = "Name: " + i.name;
        secondDiv.append(myName);

        const myExperience = document.createElement("h3");
        myExperience.innerText = "Experience: " + result.data.base_experience;
        secondDiv.append(myExperience);
        document.getElementById("secDiv").append(secondDiv);
        secArr = result.data.base_experience;  // Collect this information in Array and find largest base experience from this Group B array
        // console.log(secArray.push(secArr));
        // console.log(secArray);
        // console.log(Math.max(...secArray)); firstArr = result.data.base_experience;
        secArray.push(secArr);
        alert(
          " From Group B " +
            Math.max(...secArray) +
            " Largest Number from array " +
            secArray
        );  // Got result but i want show this element outside function for compare Group A and Group B largest value and show alert message which is largest experience Group A or Group B and show result based on largest base_experince value
      });
    });
  });

  return (
    <div
      style={{
        border: "10px solid green",
      }}
    >
      <h1>Group A</h1>
      <div
        id="firstDiv"
        style={{
          border: "1px solid blue",
          display: "flex",
          width: "100%",
        }}
      ></div>
      <h1>Group B</h1>
      <div
        id="secDiv"
        style={{
          border: "1px solid red",
          display: "flex",
          width: "100%",
        }}
      ></div>
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

Comment: Hi @jsN00b, Thanks for your valuable feedback, I've tried code same as per your suggestion but the code is executed into the infinite and not stoppable **const max1 = Math.max(...firstArray); setNum1(max1);** Same code use for the second array with setNum2 state Could you please assist me if there are any other possibilities? Thanks in advance!

Comment: It's working similar like `const max1 = Math.max(...firstArray); setNum1(max1);`  code again executed infinite and non-stoppable loop

Comment: Thanks, @jsN00b for your effort just checked your code  It's repeated images multiple time I want show it only 4 times and compare highest value from the both group